# excel: can I plot a function of an existing data set

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a line chart whose x and y values come from (column) data in a worksheet.  Instead of plotting those y 'raw' values, is there a way to plot some function of them?  For instance, plot 'y-3'?

I know I can create a new data column using the function, and plot that.  I'd just prefer to avoid that, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the X values (i.e. the independent variables-there's no way around that), but you can plot a function for Y.

1. Create a named range for your X values (e.g. xval) (even better, convert them to a data table, even if it's only one column).  You can even skip entering the x values into cells and direct enter them as an array into the name manager (using comma separated values in {} ), however, its usually easier to just put them onto a worksheet.
2. Create a second named range for your Y values (e.g. yval).  In the Edit Name box, use your function in the refers to box (e.g. xval-3).
3. Create your chart using the named ranges for your horizontal and vertical axis values (e.g. sheet1!xval and sheet1!yval)